# I'll be gone IN or ON the train?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, difference, grammaticality

Obviously we say ''I am on the train'' but if there's ''I'll be gone...'' in the sentence does it affect the grammar in any way? Is it ''I'll be gone IN or ON the train?''

Comment: No, it doesn't affect the choice of preposition.  Did you see something that implied that it would?

Answer (score 0):

I'll have gone by train.
I'll be going on the train.
I'll be going by train.

Will you be there?  No, I'll be gone, by train.